# Ng bootsrap import does not work angular 6

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to import NgbDropdown in my component, but i always get error?

I have tried like this

```
import { NgbDropdown } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

But i got this

```
AppointmentsComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgbDropdownMenu -> NgbDropdown]:
```

Does anybody have solution?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add this into your app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
  NgbModule.forRoot()
]
```

That will allow the NgbDropdown to work.

and, in your component, add this:

```
providers: [
  NgbDropdown
]
```

Comment: Yes i have added NgbModule in shared modul for root?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you import ng-bootstrap into the app.module?

```
 import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    @NgModule({
      ...
      imports: [NgbModule, ...],
declarations: [AppComponent, NgbdDropdownBasic],
      ...
    })
    export class YourAppModule {
    }
```

See you here:
[Stackblitz- example Dropdown](https://stackblitz.com/angular/oaelaaybopv?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Yes i have added NgbModule in shared modul for root?

Comment: You have added NgbDropDown in declarations

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the `NgbDropdownModule` in your corresponding module?

Please add this code to your module where the `AppointmentsComponent` is declared:

```js
import { NgbDropdownModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...,
        NgbDropdownModule
    ],...
```

Comment: Yes i have added NgbModule in shared modul for root?

Comment: Could you please provide more of your code in the question?